# What are the best materials to use for producing drinking water from the Air?

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, process-engineering, water-resources

There are several companies producing equipment that produce drinking water from the air. They use dessicants, hygroscopic brine, or deliquescent salts, to adsorb water from atmospheric humidity.  Then they use a heat source to evaporate the adsorbed water to be condensed and funneled to a collection point. Some systems use solar photovoltaics (PV) to run fans and controls, and solar heat for de-adsorption. One system claims to use the process's downward flow to create a lower pressure for de-adsorption, which makes it more efficient at lower temperatures.

I'm looking for information on electronic controls, the core of which is probably a delta-humidity-inside/outside sensors; the best adsorbant material (quantity and configuration), and the material to use for the condensation surface.

Comment: Which question are you asking? Your title is about materials, but text adds in electronic controls. There seem to be three separate questions in there. I am not an expert in this field, but the three items seem almost completely orthogonal.

Comment: It's great that you have done the literature search.  For the curious readers, could you post the links to the companies/products which you are referring to?

Comment: Decades ago, David Jones, writing as *Deadelus* in *New Scientist* or *Nature*, I forget which, suggested a passive method involving treacle. A tall column of concentrated sugar syrup, open at the top, would absorb humidity which would then diffuse to the bottom of the column where it would automatically be expelled through reverse osmosis membranes as a continuous process. This may not be the answer you were looking for, but more people should (re-)study the classics. :-)

Comment: I do not generally produce water that would be considered potable.

Comment: https://www.igb.fraunhofer.de/en/press-media/press-releases/2009/drinking-water-from-air-humidity.html

Comment: https://airsolarwater.com/produce-water-from-air-powered-by-solar-energy-overview/